# How to mock instance variable of class?

Tags: java, junit4, mockito, powermock

How do i mock the variables instantiated at class level..I want to mock GenUser,UserData. how do i do it...

I have following class

```
public class Source {

private  GenUser v1 = new GenUser();

private  UserData v2 = new UserData();

private  DataAccess v3 = new DataAccess();

public String createUser(User u) {
    return v1.persistUser(u).toString();
    }
}
```

how do i mocked my v1 is like this

```
GenUser gu=Mockito.mock(GenUser.class);
PowerMockito.whenNew(GenUser.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(gu);
```

what i have written for unit test and to mock is that

```
@Test
public void testCreateUser() {
    Source scr = new Source();
    //here i have mocked persistUser method
    PowerMockito.when(v1.persistUser(Matchers.any(User.class))).thenReturn("value");
    final String s = scr.createUser(new User());
    Assert.assertEquals("value", s);
}
```

even if i have mocked persistUser method of GenUser v1 then also it did not return me "Value" as my return val.

thanks in adavanced.......:D

Comment: How is `obj` created?

Comment: i have changed obj please check....

Comment: OK, I don't know PowerMockito (I don't have to use it ;)), but doesn't it need to `@PrepareForMock` or something? Your code extract doesn't show that

Comment: You may need to do extra preparation to replace the constructor, as fge mentioned, but a better idea is probably to create a `replaceForTest(v1, v2, v3)` method in your class (or reduce the fields from private to package-private) and make it very easy to replace those objects. Encapsulation of most things is a good idea--it helps focus and reduce the API you have to support--but by the time you introduce PowerMockito it may be a better idea to carefully relax some visibility restrictions to improve testability.

Comment: thanks jeff for reply but my question is that even if i have mocked persistUser method and mocked the return value to 'value' then also it dont return me that value

Comment: Using Powermock is always a sign of poor design. If you can change class Source, i would introduce a constructor, that let you inject a GenUser object.

Comment: @swan: Yes, and I think that it's because you haven't done all the steps you need to do to replace the constructor (like fge said), so your `scr.v1` is a real GenUser object, not a PowerMockito mock. You also switched `gu` with `v1` in the example; if that's not a StackOverflow accident, make sure you set your expectations on the exact same object you're trying to install in your `Source` under test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in fge's comment:

> All usages require `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)` and `@PrepareForTest` annotated at class level.

Make sure you're using that test runner, and that you put `@PrepareForTest(GenUser.class)` on your test class.

(Source: https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage13)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at https://code.google.com/p/mockito/wiki/MockingObjectCreation - there are a couple of ideas there that may help you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know mockito, but if you don't mind using PowerMock and EasyMock, the following would work.

```
@Test
public void testCreateUser() {
    try {
        User u = new User();
        String value = "value";    

        // setup the mock v1 for use
        GenUser v1 = createMock(GenUser.class);
        expect(v1.persistUser(u)).andReturn(value);
        replay(v1);

        Source src = new Source();
        // Whitebox is a really handy part of PowerMock that allows you to
        // to set private fields of a class.  
        Whitebox.setInternalState(src, "v1", v1);
        assertEquals(value, src.createUser(u));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // if for some reason, you get an exception, you want the test to fail
        e.printStackTrack();
        assertTrue(false);
    }
}
```